# d3.brush is selecting surrounding divs with radial chart; only occurs d3 3.3+

Tags: d3.js

When using brushes, the brushes select neighboring divs to the svg projection.

See the below to see the effect.

[image]

This doesn't occur in the pre- d3.3 versions of the library.

In 3.3, Bostock expanded brush functionality, which could cause the issue. Although, I swapped the older version of d3.svg.brush into the newer library, and it still occurs.

I need to use a newer library for some of my other functions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the older circular brushes (cbrushes) method, the answer is to replace your `if(dragging)` operator with `lines 8130 - 8138` in the new d3 svg.brush code:

```
if (dragging) {
        origin[0] = xExtent[0] - origin[0];
        origin[1] = yExtent[0] - origin[1];
      } else if (resizing) {
        var ex = +/w$/.test(resizing), ey = +/^n/.test(resizing);
        offset = [ xExtent[1 - ex] - origin[0], yExtent[1 - ey] - origin[1] ];
        origin[0] = xExtent[ex];
        origin[1] = yExtent[ey];
      } else if (d3.event.altKey) center = origin.slice();
```